# Connecting to SQL Server Using pypyodbc

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pyodbc, pypyodbc

I'm attempting to access an SQL in python using pypyodbc, here is the code I've got:

```
import pypyodbc as pyodbc
db_host = host
db_name = name
db_user = user
db_password = password
connection_string = ("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=" + (db_host) + ";DATABASE=" + (db_name) + ";UID=" + (db_user) + ";PWD=" + (db_password) + ";Trusted_Connection=yes;")
db = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
```

When I try connecting I get the following error:

```
pypyodbc.DatabaseError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.')
```

I have tried changing the connection string in a number of different ways, but it still produduces the same error each time. This is work for a school project, and such I am trying to access the SQL server from the school system, and so the only thing I can think of that would mess it up is that there is a problem with the firewall and connection or something.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: try to "telnet <hostname> <port>" first

Comment: Where should that be added?

Comment: Is your SQL Server service(s) running on machine? Check Task Manager / Services. Alternatively, can you open database in Management Studio? Finally, the user may not have access to it. Check logins in SSMS.

Comment: The server is externally hosted by a 3rd party

Comment: The `telnet <hostname> <port>` needs to be run from the command line (*nix or DOS). For example: `telnet mysqlserver.domain.com 1433`. This will tell you whether it can connect or not (if it says connected, you're good, otherwise it will hang on trying to connect).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not particular about pyodbc, one working solution through pymssql:-

```
import pymssql
import _mssql

# Connect to SQL
db_host = host
db_port = port
db_user = user
db_password = password

Conn = pymssql.connect(server=db_host,user=db_user,password=db_password, port=db_port)
```

Comment: I tried to use pymssql initially, but I was unable to because the school system I am working on wouldnt allow me to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Connection string is correct.
Check `host`, `name`, `user` and `password`.